# GetArrayFromImage - RuntimeError: No suitable template parameter can be found. Python ITK

Tags: python, itk

I would like to ask you about Watershed3D.
I tried algorithm from this page https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/itk-watershed-to-label-bubbles
Also I used their dataset

```py
def apply_watershed(in_vol, 
                    threshold = 0.01, 
                    level = 0.5):
    #(A rule of thumb is to set the Threshold to be about 1 / 100 of the Level.)
    Dimension = len(np.shape(in_vol))
    # convert to itk array and normalize
    itk_vol_img = itk.GetImageFromArray((in_vol*255.0).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
    InputImageType = itk.Image[itk.ctype('unsigned char'), Dimension]
    OutputImageType = itk.Image[itk.ctype('float'), Dimension]
    dmapOp = itk.SignedMaurerDistanceMapImageFilter[InputImageType, OutputImageType].New(Input = itk_vol_img)
    dmapOp.SetInsideIsPositive(False)
    watershedOp = itk.WatershedImageFilter.New(Input=dmapOp.GetOutput())
    watershedOp.SetThreshold(threshold)
    watershedOp.SetLevel(level)
    watershedOp.Update()
    return itk.GetArrayFromImage(dmapOp), itk.GetArrayFromImage(watershedOp)

dmap_vol, ws_vol = apply_watershed(bubble_image)
```

But I get this error:

```
itk.GetArrayFromImage(watershedOp)
Error: line 248, in _GetArrayFromImage
raise RuntimeError("No suitable template parameter can be found.")
RuntimeError: No suitable template parameter can be found.
```

The error occurs with `itk.GetArrayFromImage(watershedOp)`
The error does not occur with `itk.GetArrayFromImage(dmapOp)`.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because the variable `watershedOp` is a `ITKWatershedImageFilter` object, not an image. You can use the `GetOutput()` method to retrieve the output image.

```py
return itk.GetArrayFromImage(dmapOp.GetOutput()), itk.GetArrayFromImage(watershedOp.GetOutput())
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, your should [edit] your answer to provide an explanation of *how* this answers the question, which helps provide context for future readers. A code block by itself is not immediately useful for those who might come across the same issue later on.